# JQuery Selectors ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get all the src of images in a unordered list, here's the HTML:

```
<ul id="slideshow">
        <li>
            <h2 rel="yummy fruit!">Fruit</h2>
            <img src="images/fruit.jpg" alt="fruit" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Vegetables</h2>
            <img src="images/vegetable.jpg" alt="vegetables" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Bread</h2>
            <img src="images/bread.jpg" alt="bread" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

for that I'm using this function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
            var $images = $('#slideshow img').attr('src');;
            console.log($images);
    });
});
```

The problem is that I only get the fist src (images/fruit.jpg), then I need to randomly order that images, any help?

Comment: You want to shuffle the array of images, or you want to move the images around in the HTML?

Comment: I want to shuffle the images randomly in that unordered list

Comment: You want just the images to shuffle and not the associated text fields?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/: _“Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set […]”_ – so that shouldn’t really have come as a surprise for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is the following:

```
// gets an array of each of the <img> elements'
// src property:
var imgSources = $('img').map(function() {
  return this.src;
}).get();

// iterates over each of the <img> elements, and updates
// its src property:
$('img').prop('src', function() {
  // index: is a random number between 0 and the last index of
  // the array:
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgSources.length),
  // source: one of the array elements:
    source = imgSources[index];
  // removing the used array-element, to ensure all elements are used,
  // and there are no duplicates:
  imgSources.splice(index, 1);

  // returning the found-element as the new src:
  return source;
});
```

```js
var imgSources = $('img').map(function() {
  return this.src;
}).get();

$('img').prop('src', function() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgSources.length),
    source = imgSources[index];
  imgSources.splice(index, 1);
  return source;
});
```

```css
h2 + img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slideshow">
  <li>
    <h2 rel="yummy fruit!">Fruit</h2>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/Image%201" alt="fruit" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Vegetables</h2>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nightlife/Image%202" alt="vegetables" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Bread</h2>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/Image%203" alt="bread" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It's just occurred to me that this could be easily implemented in native JavaScript, and almost as simply:

```
// retrieving a NodeList of all <img> elements, using
// Array.prototype.slice, with Function.prototype.call(),
// to convert that NodeList to an Array:
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), 0),
  // Array.prototype.map used to create a new Array,
  // storing the src properties of each of the <img> elements:
  imgSources = images.map(function(img) {
    // img: the current <img> from the array of <img>s over
    // which we're iterating:
    return img.src;
  });

// iterating over each of the <img> elements:
images.forEach(function(img) {
  // img: again the current <img> element from the array
  // of images.

  // creating a random number between 0 and one less-than
  // (using Math.floor()) the length of the array:
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgSources.length),
    // caching an element from the imgSources array:
    newSource = imgSources[index];

  // removing the array-element, at the random index point,
  // from the array:
  imgSources.splice(index, 1);

  // updating the src property of the current <img>:
  img.src = newSource;
});
```

```js
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), 0),
  imgSources = images.map(function(el) {
    return el.src;
  });

images.forEach(function(img) {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgSources.length),
    newSource = imgSources[index];
  imgSources.splice(index, 1);
  img.src = newSource;
});
```

```css
h2 + img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slideshow">
  <li>
    <h2 rel="yummy fruit!">Fruit</h2>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/Image%201" alt="fruit" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Vegetables</h2>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nightlife/Image%202" alt="vegetables" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Bread</h2>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/Image%203" alt="bread" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
  - [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByTagName).
  - [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).
  - [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
  - [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Not to promote my answer, but this sure seems overly complicated and unclear what you're doing without extensive code comments.

Comment: Does it? I find it quite simple (but that's maybe because of familiarity with jQuery and its methods); I will note that your answer *seems* to miss half the question, or is your shuffling implemented in a manner that I can't see? Bearing in mind that getting the array is the first three lines, which seems, to me, far simpler than your own approach.

Comment: you're right, i did miss part about randomly ordering them. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each `img` to get the sources like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        var images = new Array();
        $('#slideshow img').each(function (index, element){
            images.push(element.attr('src'));
        });
        console.log(images);
    });
});
```

This gets all the sources into a list. If you'd like to randomly order the list, there are plenty of resources on how to do this in javascript, here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/526704